# Java GMAIL SMTP MAILSEND ERROR- 553 5.1.2 The address specified is not a valid RFC-5321 address

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

This is the code I am using. It worked perfectly until today but its not working now. Does any body have the same issue?

```
   Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.user", "username@gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.password", "passwordtext");
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("username@gmail.com", "passwordtext");
        }
    };
    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("username@gmail.com"));
    msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("toaddress@gmail.com"));
    msg.setSubject("hiiiii");
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());

    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setContent("ggggg", "text/html");

    msg.setContent(multipart);

   Transport.send(msg);
```

Comment: If it's worked perfect until tomorrow, what is the problem? Can you give an example of an address it's given this error for?

Comment: soryy all...actualy in my code i am using like msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("username"));changed this to msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("username@gmail.com")); and this worked fine

Comment: but msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("username")); worked till yesterday

Comment: "Its worked perfect till tomorrow.But its not working now". time travel paradox ?

Answer (score 0):

> In my code i am using like:

> ```
>    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("username"));
> ```

> changed this to

> ```
>    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("username@gmail.com"));
> ```

> and this worked fine ... but

> ```
>    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("username"));
> ```

> worked till yesterday.

It is a puzzle why it (apparently) worked until yesterday with an invalid email address.  However, the solution is obvious.  Always use a full [RFC-5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) compatible email address ... like the error message says.

Note that the [constructor's javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#InternetAddress(java.lang.String)) says this:

> *"Parse the given string and create an InternetAddress. See the parse method for details of the parsing. The address is parsed using "strict" parsing. This constructor does not perform the additional syntax checks that the InternetAddress(String address, boolean strict) constructor does when strict is true. This constructor is equivalent to InternetAddress(address, false).*

> *Parameters: address - the address in RFC822 format*

> *Throws: AddressException - if the parse failed"*